# how to hide button title but can still call it using sender.currentTitle?

Tags: swift

I added a button in the main storyboard in Xcode. This button has an image as the background and its title "blueDoor" is shown on top of the background (see photo below).

There will be three buttons like this and they are linked to one IBAction.  I would like to use `sender.currentTitle` to let the program know which button is clicked, but I don't want the text to show on the image.

How can I hide the text but still keep the title attribute so `sender.currentTitle` can be used? Or is there another way to do so?

A button with an image as the background:

[image: a button with image as background]

Comment: Why don't you use three different action methods? If you must use the same action method, then you can define different tag values for each button. Check out [viewWithTag](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622429-viewwithtag)

Comment: I am trying to make an app of Monty Hall problem. I need to keep clicking different buttons so using three different action methods doesn't work well  in my opinion. But the tag values worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tag` to do this.

> Open storyboard > select your button > select `Show the Attributes Inspector` section in the right bar of the Xcode > scroll down and find `Tag` under the `View` section. And give different tags to your buttons.

Then your `IBAction` should be like this ->

```swift
@IBAction func didTapMyButtons(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag:
    case 0: // it is your first button's tag
        // Do something with button which has tag `0`

    case 1: // it is your second button's tag
        // Do something with button which has tag `1`

    case 2: // it is your third button's tag
        // Do something with button which has tag `2`

    default: break
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly: you can not do that. The `currentTitle` property is essentially a getter for `button.titleLable.text`. So is `title(for: UIControl.State)` setter (`setTitle(String?, for: UIControl.State)`)

What [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/currentTitle%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/currentTitle) say:

> `var currentTitle: String? { get }`
>
> Discussion
>
> The value for this property is set automatically whenever
>   the button state changes. For states that do not have a custom title
>   string associated with them, this method returns the title that is
>   currently displayed, which is typically the one associated with the
>   normal state. The value may be nil.

This means whatever changes you bring to `titleLabel.text`, it is automatically reflected on a `currentTitle` property.

You can use tags as suggested or add a custom action handler for every button as you create them. E.g. for cancel and proceed buttons one will do it like so:

```
self.cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.cancelActionMethod), for: .touchUpInside)
self.proceedButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.proceedActionMethod), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And then somewhere inside self:

```
@objc func cancelActionMethod() {
    // some cancel specific actions
}
@objc func proceedActionMethod() {
    // some cancel specific actions
}
```